# How to prove that "3 is a prime" in the Isabelle proof assistant?

Tags: isabelle

For a proof I'm working on in Isabelle I need the facts that 3 and 5 are primes. What would be the simplest way to establish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are simp rules that allow the simplifier to do that automatically:

```
lemma "prime (5 :: nat)"
  by simp
```

For larger numbers (e.g. `137`), this will take a few seconds, and for much larger numbers, it is completely unusable.

You can also use `eval` instead of `simp`, which goes through Isabelle's evaluation oracle to evaluate the statement inside Standard ML and then reinterprets the result as a theorem in Isabelle. Depending on whom you ask, this may be seen as slightly less trustworthy than `simp`.

Lastly, there the entry on [Pratt Certificates](https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/Pratt_Certificate.html) in the *Archive of Formal Proofs* also provides a proof method called `pratt`, which can automatically prove the primality of a number using Pratt certificates. This is slightly more efficient than using `simp`, but still not great for really big numbers.

In any case, for small numbers like 5 and 7, `by simp` is the way to go.

Note however that you *must* give a type, i.e. `prime (5 :: nat)` or `prime (7 :: int)`. If you just write `prime 5`, the type that is inferred for 5 is too general. For instance, `prime (5 :: real)` is *not* true, since fields contain no prime numbers.